# How to Pass input type "file" value onto Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io

This may sounds simple, but I really got stuck on how to pass a value of  onto a Codeigniter controllers. I have a logic on my controller that If the value of input type file is empty, it will be processed on function A of my model, or else on function B of my model.

Like this:

```
'if($newimage==''|$newimage==null){
    $this->mymodel->dofullpart();
 }
else{
    $this->mymodel->dopart();
'
```

I've tried to catch it on controller using:

```
'$newimage=$this->input->post('imagename');'
```

But I didn't get any value, although I printed it, there is nothing shown.
Then I tried to catch it using:

```
'$newimage=$_FILES['imagename']['name'];'
```

Yes, the value retrieved successfully when I did select any file, and not retrieved when I didn't select any.

Another problem comes, everytime I edit other part of my form except selecting image, the $newimage always get value consists of two characters like = 'Ut' or 'Yt' which I suspect it was generated randomly by $_FILES. It makes my logic upthere not working.

Is there any more safe way to get the value and catch it precisely whether it is not selected or selected?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the directory named as you want, for example, uploads as directory name in the root directory of project. Then config the upload path, file size, file extension and so on. For more details see the link [File Upload document from ellislab](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) and my below code.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('filename_in_html_input', 'filename_in_html_input', 'required');
```

//the above line is for validation.

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->set_allowed_types('gif|jpg|png|jpeg|zip|pdf|doc|docx');   
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename_in_html_input')) 
        {
        //error message
        }
 else
{
$this->upload->do_upload('filename_in_html_input')
//upload process
}
```

Comment: I think it is to input/upload a file. What I want to achieve is only getting the value of input type file (the path or file name) and use it as parameter in my IF logic.

Comment: $finfo = $this->upload->data();
echo $finfo['file_name'];

Comment: In this case, that won't do since I only want to retrieve and catch the value of input type file in my form onto a variable in my controller. Let me say I have a variable in controller named $newimage where it should contains the value of that input file, whether I select a file or not.

Comment: I'm gonna try it, and will be back soon for an update. I still can't imagine why I have to do_upload first to get the value of an input type file like what you suggest me. Thanks anyway, much appreciate